# content of Informational packets in ipsec between phase1 & phase2

Tags: ipsec, ike

I want to know about Informational packets in IKE negotiation between main mode & quick mode. what are the contents those packets will contain?

here i am uploading the screen shot of ike negotiations[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through the rfc 2409 for IKE.
It gives the details about why ,where and when informational packets are required.
Hope it helps!!

[Link to IKE rfc2409](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2409.txt)

Comment: yeah, i have gone through that RFC, there it is mentioned. Thanks man..